# Loop through arrays manually

Tags: numpy

I am trying to replicate how zip works by using a simple example and i want the output to be an array.
I have the following data

```
s = (2, 2)
array = np.zeros(s)
x = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1])
y = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1])
```

What i want to do is have a 2x2 matrix as output, which works like this:

```
for i, j in zip(x, y):
    array[i][j] += 1
```

This outputs

```
[[2 0]
 [2 4]]
```

I tried obtaining the same results without using the zip for lists but i get a (1,1) tuple

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    array = x[i], y[i]
```

will output: `(1, 1)`

Comment: `zip` iterates over the lists **elements**, your attempts iterates over the **indices**. Also, in the `zip` example you are `+= 1`, in your attempt you are not (and that assignment attempt is wrong). Anyway, try using `array[x[i]][y[i]] += 1`, just be wary of `IndexError`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in range(len(x)):
  array[x[i]][y[i]] += 1
```

This will do the same as

```
for i, j in zip(x, y):
    array[i][j] += 1
```

Comment: Just be warned that `zip` automatically stops iterating when the shorter iterable is exhausted. `range(len...` will not. Also, since `zip` iterates over the elements, using `range(len...` can easily cause `IndexError`

Answer (score 0):

This makes the transformation clear for you

```
for idx in range(len(x)):
    i = x[idx]
    j = y[idx]
    array[i][j] += 1

print(array)
```

Output:

```
[[2 0]
 [2 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
array = np.zeros(2, dtype=int)
x = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1])
y = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1])

# empirically what zip does
[(x[i], y[i]) for i in range(sorted([len(x), len(y)])[0])]

#proof
print( list(zip(x, y)) == [(x[i], y[i]) for i in range(sorted([len(x), len(y)])[0])] )
```

```
True
```

Why use sorted?

Since zip stops at the index of the smaller list we need to iterate by the range of the smallest list; therefore `sorted([1,2])[0]` is `1` (the smaller of the 2)

so even if i had `y = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1])` that would still return the correct zip of the 2

Answer (score 0):

In order to do it in a vectorized way, try to [work](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) on `array.ravel()` instead. This command performs dynamic changes of `array`:

```
np.add.at(array.ravel(), 
          np.ravel_multi_index(np.array([x,y]), s), 
          np.repeat(1, len(x)))
```

So you can check out after running it that `array` has changed:

```
>>> array
array([[2, 0],
       [2, 4]])
```